# Changing publisher name and URL

Tags: drupal, ckan

So, yeah, the [form](https://github.com/datagovuk/ckanext-dgu/blob/master/ckanext/dgu/theme/templates/publisher/edit_form.html#L71) is saying:

> Please contact the system administrator to change your publisher name

and I'm the system administrator for the project and I don't know what the hell am I doing. :)

I can change the name of the publisher but not the URL. I guess this also changes some URL in the dataset? Do I need to do the change with API or there is some GUI?

BTW. I'm using DGU package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ssh to your server and run commands like this to change the name, and optionally the title too with the -t:

```
source /home/co/ckan/bin/activate && cd /vagrant/src/ckanext-dgu
python ../ckanext-dgu/ckanext/dgu/bin/publisher_rename.py $CKAN_INI highways-agency highways-england -t 'Highways England'
```

From: http://guidance.data.gov.uk/publisher_editing.html#rename-a-publisher

The problem is it can take a few minutes to rename and reindex all the datasets, so this often can't be done during a web request. Ideally someone would code this as a background task so this can still be done in the form. However in the meantime DGU implemented this command-line script to do it, hence the need for a sysadmin.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you! BTW. I'm having some older version without that script so I just downloaded it and run it.